Automate debug java with rlwrap
I use rlwrap to debug a Java process
rlwrap jdb -attach 192.168.5.55:9999

When the breakpoint stop:
> stop in  comm.app.aaa.func
> set a = 0
> cont

I do that few times, each time the breakpoint stop
How can I do that automatically without wait for breakpoint?

You can try using expect to automate your flow. Sample expect script:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 120
spawn jdb -attach 192.168.5.55:9999

expect "> "
send "stop in comm.app.aaa.func\n"

for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    expect -re {\[\d\] }
    send "set a = 0\n"
    expect -re {\[\d\] }
    send "cont\n"
}


try creating a command file like somecommand.txt
stop in comm.app.aaa.func
set a = 0
cont

and then feed the command to jdb
rlwrap jdb -attach 192.168.5.55:9999 < somecommand.txt

OR
run an inline script
echo -e "stop in comm.app.aaa.func\nset a = 0\ncont" | rlwrap jdb -attach 192.168.5.55:9999


Hope this helps
